# How can I add an axis on right hand side of graph in R -further development of Pareto Chart

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis

Pareto Chart continues to be under development.

Effect is replaced by Half_Effect and should be labelled as |Half Effect| on y axis. How to do. I keep getting errors.

pareto.chart with cumulative Percent line is not ok. I need to coordinate this with an axis on the right hand side of the graph. How to do?

ChartData

EffectX is used to identify position on x axis, it is specific to this data. I would like this to be generic

```
#  EffectX Frequency Cum.Freq Percentage Cum.Percent  
#1    0.65  10.43800 10.43800  39.295364    39.29536
#2    2.00   6.52080 16.95880  24.548497    63.84386
#3    3.20   5.64580 22.60460  21.254432    85.09829
#4    4.40   1.56250 24.16710   5.882258    90.98055
#5    5.50   0.97917 25.14627   3.686227    94.66678
#6    6.75   0.77083 25.91710   2.901901    97.56868
#7    8.05   0.64583 26.56293   2.431321   100.00000

EffectNames=c( "Pull Back(A)","Hook(B)", "Peg(C)","AB", "BC", "AC", "ABC")
Half_Effect=c( 10.4,6.5,5.6,1.6,0.98,.77,.65 )
paretoData=data.frame(EffectNames, Half_Effect)
paretoData
paretoData$EffectNames = factor(paretoData$EffectNames, 
    levels=c("Pull Back(A)","Hook(B)", "Peg(C)","AB", "BC", "AC", "ABC"))
p=ggplot(paretoData, aes(x=EffectNames, y=Half_Effect)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
geom_text(aes(label=Half_Effect), vjust=1.5, colour="white")+
geom_line(data=chartData,aes(x=EffectX,y=Cum.Percent))
p
```

Sincerely, MM

Comment: Secondary y axes are intentionally (mostly) unsupported in **ggplot2**. The linked duplicate discusses this at length, along with various fragile, unsupported work-arounds. The dev version of ggplot _does_ have support for a second y axis, but only if it is a direct transformation of the the original y axis.

Comment: Thank you for  your reply. I will check on it.